# Elastic - Multiple filter query syntax

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello I have the following query that I am running:

```
{
  "_source": [
    "source1",
    "source2",
    "source3",
    "source4",
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "must": {
        "filter": [
            {
            "term": {
              "_type": {
                "value": "someval1"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "_type": {
                "value": "someval2"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "query_string": {
          "analyze_wildcard": "true",
          "query": "tesla*",
          "rewrite": "scoring_boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ]
}
```

That is currently returning:

```
'"reason":"[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":343},"status":400}'
```

Any idea how to use multiple filters on a query? I was able to do it just fine on elastic 2.4 but since OR is now deprecated as well as filtered, I am a bit lost.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the query is wrong. `filter` should not be wrapped into the `must` statement. It should be in the same level with `must`. Also `bool` queries `must` statement should be an array, not an object. So your query should look like this

```
{
    "_source":[
       "source1",
       "source2",
       "source3",
       "source4"
    ],
    "query":{
       "bool":{
          "minimum_should_match":1,
          "must":[
             {
                "query_string":{
                   "analyze_wildcard":"true",
                   "query":"tesla*",
                   "rewrite":"scoring_boolean"
                }
             }
          ],
          "filter":{
             "bool":{
                "should":[
                   {
                      "term":{
                         "_type":{
                            "value":"someval1"
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   {
                      "term":{
                         "_type":{
                            "value":"someval2"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
       }
    },
    "size":50,
    "sort":[
       "_score"
    ]
 }
```

I think your filter is `OR`, that's why I wrap it inside `should`